# Zapier - Prevent query parameter names getting URL encoded

Tags: urlencode, zapier

We are running into an issue with Zapier where it's URL encoding our query parameter names which then doesn't get parsed correctly on API side.
Our parameters might look like this:

```
Where.Name[eq]=john
```

however the parameter after it's being used in Zapier ends up looking like this:

```
Where.Name%5Beq%5D=john
```

Is there any way how to tell Zapier to not URL encode the query parameter name part?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using skipEncodingChars field in z.request (from version 11.3.2+)

[https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/a3bf8eefa6d0dc41c4001bd74f48873eb85ad1d9/packages/schema/docs/build/schema.md#:~:text=to%20false.-,skipEncodingChars,-no](https://github.com/zapier/zapier-platform/blob/a3bf8eefa6d0dc41c4001bd74f48873eb85ad1d9/packages/schema/docs/build/schema.md#:%7E:text=to%20false.-,skipEncodingChars,-no)

> `skipEncodingChars` | no | `string` | Contains the characters that you want left unencoded in the query params (`req.params`). If unspecified, `z.request()` will percent-encode non-ascii characters and these reserved characters: `` :$/?#[]@$&+,;=^@`\ ``.

Comment: Confirming that this solved my issue, thanks a lot!